# modal is not triggering on button click in materialize css

Tags: jquery, css, html, materialize

I have made an modal  using materrialize css a and want to open it from navbar anchor tag. code seems to correct but not unable to open the dialog .

here is the code,

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">  
        <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper indigo darken-4">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="modal-trigger" href="#abc">Post</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class=""><b>Forum</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" ><b>About</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
 </div> 


    <!-- start modal -->
    <div id="abc" class="modal">

        <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" id="closemodal" data-dismiss="modal" id="closemodal">&times;</button>
             <div class="row">
             <div class="col s6" style="padding-top:25px;">
             <h4 >Personal Details</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="col s6">
             <h4>Book Details</h4>
             </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
            <div class="row">
            <!-- personal details -->
            <div class="col s6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input placeholder="" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                        <label for="first_name" style="font-size:12px;"><b>First Name</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input placeholder="" id="MiddleName" name="MiddleName" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="middle_name" style="font-size:12px;"><b>Middle Name</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input placeholder="" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="last_name" style="font-size:12px;"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s2">
                <input name="gender" type="radio" id="male" value="Male">
                <label for="gender" style="font-size:12px;">Male</label>

            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s2">
                <input name="gender" type="radio" id="female" value="Female">
                <label for="gender" style="font-size:12px;">Female</label>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input placeholder="" id="location" name="location" type="text" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                    <label for="location" style="font-size:12px;">Location</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input placeholder="" id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                    <label for="email" style="font-size:12px;">Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input placeholder="" id="mobile" name="mobile" type="number" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                    <label for="mobile" style="font-size:12px;">Mobile</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <textarea placeholder="" rows="3" id="message" name="message" class="materialize-textarea" style="font-size:12px"></textarea>
                    <label for="message" style="font-size:12px;">Message</label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="reset" name="reset" style="float:right;margin-left:10px;">Reset
                    <i class="material-icons right">shuffle</i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit" style="float:right;">post
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
                </div>


        </div>

            <!-- book details -->
            <div class="col s6">

            <table id="booktable">
                    <tr class="clone">
                    <div class="row">
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input placeholder="" id="booktitle" name="booktitle" type="text" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                                <label for="book_title" style="font-size:12px;">BookTitle</label>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input placeholder="" id="bookgenre" name="bookgenre" type="text" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                                <label for="book_genre" style="font-size:12px;">BookGenre</label>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input placeholder="" id="bookwriter" name="bookwriter" type="text" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                                <label for="book_writer" style="font-size:12px;">BookWriter</label>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input placeholder="" id="bookdescription" name="bookdescription" type="text" class="validate" style="font-size:12px">
                                <label for="book_description" style="font-size:12px;">Description</label>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone" id="addmore">Add More</a></p>

            </div>  
            <!-------- end books --->   
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        </div>
```

please do reply. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

modals needs to be initialized using this script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
 });
```

Comment: this is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g188jhk/) have you add jquery ? see in my example all the dependencies that are needed.

Comment: sorry it's not working. it should be opened by anchor tag but m unable to figure out why it's not opening

Comment: What do you mean by **anchor tag**? Is it the **#post** button only or something else? I checked @giuseppe straziota's jsfiddle, it is working. **The post button is triggering the modal.**

Comment: I've modified the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rjjad0sp/  in this example you open and close the modal with jquery. I hope it solves your problem, in negative case, have you checked the browser console?

Comment: sorry @Cooolranjan I can't fix your code, the jsfiddle works and the only thing that I've done is to add the js and css and write the script code that call the leanmodal at the ready of the document.